# Fireabase snapShot is not working on react typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am recently learning the React, and firebase. I've encountered this problem for like 2 days still I can't solve it. There is an error when I use snapShot from firebase when I am retrieving something.

Here is the code:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await getDocs(collection(db, "post"))

      onSnapshot(result, (snap:any) => {
        const newArray:any[] = [];
        snap.forEach((doc:any) => {
            if(doc !== newArray){
              newArray.push({title: doc.data().title, content: doc.data().content, user_id:doc.data().user_id, id: doc.id})
            }
          });
          setPost([...post, newArray]);
      });
    }
```

Here is my error:

> TS2769: No overload matches this call.   The last overload gave the
> following error.
> Argument of type 'QuerySnapshot' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Query'.
> Type 'QuerySnapshot' is missing the following properties from type 'Query': converter, type, firestore,
> withConverter

Please help me, I am new to Typescript (although I face angular before React is quite new to me, and so does firebase)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onSnapshot()` function takes either a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference) or a [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.collectionreference) a first parameter but you are passing a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.querysnapshot). You don't have to fetch document explicitly before using a listener. Try:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  const colRef = collection(db, "post");

  onSnapshot(colRef, (snap: any) => {
    // ... handle response
  });
}
```

Comment: OMG it works. Thank you so much! I'm stuck with this error for like a day now.